# Azure DevOps Wiki Pages - Permissions - Create a Wiki

Tags: azure, azure-devops-wiki

My project administrator in our organization set up a wiki for our project; however, I can only read the wiki and cant create any sub wiki pages or delete. I requested for my permissions to be "Contributor" and even changed my account to "Project Administrator" and still I cannot create new Wiki pages/Sub pages.

Please give me instructions on how a project administrator can grant me permissions for creating  wikis and sub-wikis.

I tried going to Project settings -> Permissions -> name of user/group.

but see nothing regarding setting up wiki permissions.
[image]

I even tried modifying the wiki security settings following this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/manage-readme-wiki-permissions?view=azure-devopshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/manage-readme-wiki-permissions?view=azure-devops

Yet still no change.

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one Devops Private project `sri` in which I added `Devi` user as **Project Administrator** like this:

[image]

When I signed in with `Devi` user, I'm able to read existing wiki's but unable to add subpage or edit it as those options are **greyed out** like below:

[image]

From this [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/manage-readme-wiki-permissions?view=azure-devops#private-projects),

> Users with **`Stakeholder`** access in a **private** project can read provisioned wiki pages and view revisions, however they can't do any edit operations.
>
> For example, Stakeholders can't create, edit, reorder, or revert
> changes to project wiki pages. These permissions **can't be** changed.

When I checked **access level** of `Devi` user from Organization's settings, it is **`Stackholder`** like below:

[image]

In your case, check if your access level is **`Stakeholder`** and change it to `Basic` access level by assigning proper license.

When I signed with other user having **`Basic`** access level, I'm able to create sub pages in Wiki successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Stakeholders or users not able to edit AzureDevOps Wiki by **Shan**](https://www.azuredevopsguide.com/stakeholders-or-users-not-able-to-edit-azuredevops-wiki/)